# Count pages automatically and display the page number for printing out

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I've been working on a Vue.js application to generate invoices, and part of this process involves ensuring that each printed page displays the correct page number. However, I've hit a snag: when I print the invoice, all pages are labeled as "Page 1 of 20," regardless of their actual position within the document. This inconsistency is puzzling, and I'm unsure how to address it. Any insights or suggestions on troubleshooting and resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <div style="background-color: lightgray" >
    <div style="background-color: white;margin: auto;width: 29.7cm" id="printable-content">
      <div class="tfoot " id="pageFooter" style="display: none">
        <div class="footerHolder" style="">
          <div class="invoice-footer">
            <div class="" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;border-radius: 8px;padding: 10px 10px 0">
              <div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-between;gap: 30px">
                <div style="width: 50%;border-right: 1px solid lightgray;padding-right: 10px">
                  <h6 class="font-size-12">Köpare</h6>
                  <div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-between;gap: 20px">
                    <div style="width: 50%;">
                      <label for="">Datum</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 50%;">
                      <label for="">Ort</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pb-2">
                    <label for="">Signatur</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 50%">
                  <h6 class="font-size-12">Säljare</h6>
                  <div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-between;gap: 20px">
                    <div style="width: 50%;">
                      <label for="">Datum</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 50%;">
                      <label for="">Ort</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pb-2">
                    <label for="">Signatur</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <small style="font-size: 8px"> Köparen har tagit del av och godkänt Testbolaget Bil ABs
              integritetspolicy</small>
            <div class="mt-2"
                 style=" display: flex; justify-content: space-between; border-top: 1px solid lightgray;  padding: 10px;">
              <div>
                <h6 class="font-size-12">xxx</h6>
                <div class="font-size-10">
                  <div>Munkforsplan 37</div>
                  <div> xxxxxx</div>
                  <div> xxxx</div>
                  <div>xxxxxx</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h6 class="font-size-12">Kontaktuppgifter</h6>
                <div class="d-flex gap-1 font-size-10">
                  <div>
                    <div>Telefon:</div>
                    <div>E-post</div>
                    <div>Hemsidan:</div>
                    <div>Adress:</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                    <div>xxxxxxx</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h6 class="font-size-12">Betalningsuppgifter</h6>
                <div class="d-flex gap-1 font-size-10">
                  <div>
                    <div>Bank:</div>
                    <div>Bankkonto</div>
                    <div>Bankgiro:</div>
                    <div>Plusgiro:</div>
                    <div>Swish:</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div>SEB</div>
                    <div>2311 321231233122</div>
                    <div>321-31111</div>
                    <div>321-31111</div>
                    <div>S070 414 3308</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Display the page number -->
        <div class="page-number"></div>
      </div>
      <table >
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="invoice-header d-flex align-baseline justify-content-between">
              <div class="d-flex align-baseline justify-content-between flex-column">
                <div>
                  <h2 style="  font-weight: 500; color: #191919;font-size: 32px">Köpavtal</h2>
                  <div>No:12312312312312</div>
                  <div>Invoice date: 12312312312312</div>
                  <div>xxx</div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="d-flex align-baseline  flex-column">
             
                <div class="mt-2">
                  <h5>Kunduppgifter</h5>
                  <div>xxxxx</div>
                  <div>xxxxx</div>
                  <div>xxxxxxx</div>
                  <div>xxxxxxx</div>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="page-header-space"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="invoice-body mt-1">
              <div style="" class="mb-3">
                <h5>text</h5>
                <div style="border: 1px solid lightgray; border-radius: 8px; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                  <div
                      style="    display: flex; justify-content: space-between; border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;  padding: 10px;">
                    <div>
                      <label for="">text</label>
                      <div>text</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="">text</label>
                      <div>text-text -text</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="">text</label>
                      <div>text</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="">text</label>
                      <div>text</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="">text</label>
                      <div>text</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div style="    display: flex; justify-content: space-between;  padding: 10px;">
                    <div>
                      <label for="">text</label>
                      <div>text</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="">text</label>
                      <div>654564</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="">text</label>
                      <div>text</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="">text</label>
                      <div>text</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="">Garanti</label>
                      <div>text</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="">Momsredovisning</label>
                      <div>text</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="invoiceTableHolder">
                <table class="invoice-table table">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Pris ex.</th>
                    <th>Moms</th>
                    <th>Pris ink.</th>
                    <th>Totalt</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="item.id">
                    <td>{{ item.name }} {{ index }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.vat }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price_in }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.totalt }} sek</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="item.id">
                    <td>{{ item.name }} {{ index }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.vat }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price_in }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.totalt }} sek</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="item.id">
                    <td>{{ item.name }} {{ index }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.vat }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price_in }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.totalt }} sek</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="item.id">
                    <td>{{ item.name }} {{ index }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.vat }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price_in }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.totalt }} sek</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="item.id">
                    <td>{{ item.name }} {{ index }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.vat }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price_in }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.totalt }} sek</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="item.id">
                    <td>{{ item.name }} {{ index }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.vat }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price_in }} sek</td>
                    <td>{{ item.totalt }} sek</td>
                  </tr>

                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-2 rejectBreak" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;border-radius: 8px;padding: 10px">
                <div class="finansHolder d-flex">
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx %</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx %</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxxr</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">xxx</label>
                    <div>xxx</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-2 mb-3 rejectBreak" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;border-radius: 8px;padding: 10px">
                <h6 class="font-size-12">Notering</h6>
                <div style="min-height: 10px">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                  massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="tfootHolder">
              <div class="footerHolder" style="">
                <div class="invoice-footer">
                  <div class="" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;border-radius: 8px;padding: 10px 10px 0">
                    <div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-between;gap: 30px">
                      <div style="width: 50%;border-right: 1px solid lightgray;padding-right: 10px">
                        <h6 class="font-size-12">Köpare11</h6>
                        <div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-between;gap: 20px">
                          <div style="width: 50%;">
                            <label for="">Datum</label>
                          </div>
                          <div style="width: 50%;">
                            <label for="">Ort</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pb-2">
                          <label for="">Signatur</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div style="width: 50%">
                        <h6 class="font-size-12">Säljare</h6>
                        <div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-between;gap: 20px">
                          <div style="width: 50%;">
                            <label for="">Datum</label>
                          </div>
                          <div style="width: 50%;">
                            <label for="">Ort</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pb-2">
                          <label for="">Signatur</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <small style="font-size: 8px"> Köparen har tagit del av och godkänt Testbolaget Bil ABs
                    integritetspolicy</small>
                  <div class="mt-2"
                       style=" display: flex; justify-content: space-between; border-top: 1px solid lightgray;  padding: 10px;">
                    <div>
                      <h6 class="font-size-12">xxx</h6>
                      <div class="font-size-10">
                        <div>xxx 37</div>
                        <div> xxxxxx</div>
                        <div> xxxx</div>
                        <div>xxxxxx</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <h6 class="font-size-12">Kontaktuppgifter</h6>
                      <div class="d-flex gap-1 font-size-10">
                        <div>
                          <div>Telefon:</div>
                          <div>E-post</div>
                          <div>Hemsidan:</div>
                          <div>Adress:</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <div>xxxxx</div>
                          <div>xxxx</div>
                          <div>xxxx</div>
                          <div>xxxxxxx</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <h6 class="font-size-12">Betalningsuppgifter</h6>
                      <div class="d-flex gap-1 font-size-10">
                        <div>
                          <div>Bank:</div>
                          <div>Bankkonto</div>
                          <div>Bankgiro:</div>
                          <div>Plusgiro:</div>
                          <div>Swish:</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <div>xx</div>
                          <div>xxx</div>
                          <div>xx-x</div>
                          <div>xxx-xxx</div>
                          <div>xxx</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="page-footer-space"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="page-footer-space"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="invoice">
    <!-- Your invoice content here -->

    <!-- Page number -->
    <span class="page-number"> <span class="page-counter"></span></span>
  </div>


</template>
<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pageNumber: 1, // Initialize the page number
      items: [
        {name: "Item 1", quantity: 2, price: 10, vat: 20, price_in: 1200, totalt: 2000},
        {name: "Item 2 with a long name that needs to be truncated", quantity: 1, price: 20},
        {name: "Item 3", quantity: 3, price: 15},
        {name: "Item 1", quantity: 2, price: 10},
        {name: "Item 2 with a long name that needs to be truncated", quantity: 1, price: 20},
        {name: "Item 3", quantity: 3, price: 15},
        {name: "Item 3", quantity: 3, price: 15},

      ]
    };

    
  },
 
  methods: {
  limitNameLength(name) {
    const maxLength = 20;
    return name.length > maxLength ? name.substring(0, maxLength) + '...' : name;
  },
  updatePageCounter(totalPages) {
    const currentPage = this.pageNumber; // Use the component's data property
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const pageCounterElement = document.querySelector('.page-counter');
      if (pageCounterElement) {
        document.querySelector('.page-counter').textContent = currentPage;
        pageCounterElement.textContent = `Page ${currentPage} of ${totalPages}`;
      }
    });
  },
},

mounted() {
    const totalPages = 20;
    this.updatePageCounter(totalPages);
  },


};

</script>

<style lang="scss">
thead td, tfoot td {
  padding: 20px;
}

tbody tr td {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}


.rejectBreak {
  page-break-after: always;
}


@media print {
  .page-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
    text-align: right;
  thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  }

  tfoot {
    display: table-footer-group;
  }

  button {
    display: none;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  tfoot .tfootHolder {
    display: none;
  }
  .tfoot {
    display: block !important;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 29.7cm;

  }
  .page-footer-space {
    height: 300px;
  }

  @page {
    size: A4;
  }


  .page {
    page-break-after: always;
    position: relative;
    height: 95vh; /* Adjust based on your content and page size */
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .page:last-child {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
  .page-number {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .page-counter::before {
  content: counter(); 
} 
}

</style>
```

many vue codes to count it correctly but not working.

Comment: the page number comes from `this.pageNumber` which shows no signs of ever being updated in your code past it's initialization of value `1`.  If it is ever updated somehow, you need to show that code, otherwise it always having a value of `1` is expected.